# No Ident Response Python IRC

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I'm not getting a "Ident" Response with this IRC Connection

```
import sys
import time
import socket 
server="irc.freenode.net" 
botnick="Hidden" 
channel="Hidden"

#Establish connection 
irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
irc.connect((server,6667)) 
irc.setblocking(False)
time.sleep(1)

time.sleep(1) 
irc.send(("/NICK "+botnick+"\r\n").encode('UTF-8'))
time.sleep(1) 
irc.send(("/JOIN "+channel+"\r\n").encode('UTF-8'))

while 1: 
 time.sleep(0.1) 
 try: 
      text=irc.recv(2040) 
      print(text) 
 except Exception: 
      pass
if text.find("PING")!=-1:
irc.send(("Test").encode('UTF-8'))
input()
```

and this is the console Output

```
b':wilhelm.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your       
hostname...\r\n:
wilhelm.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident\r\n:
wilhelm.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Found your hostname\r\n'
b':wilhelm.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** No Ident response\r\n'
```

It just hangs for about 5-10 seconds then says closing link to 127.0.0.1
then says b'' multiple times

Code inspired from
http://agzuniverse.blogspot.ca/2016/05/irc-bot-in-python-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

identd [RFC1413](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1413.html) is a service used to associate connections coming from multiuser hosts with the users who "own" those connections. It used to be more widely used, with older SMTP and NNTP servers frequently configured to log identd responses, but today it's largely fallen out of use except for IRC servers.

Originally, IRC servers checked for ident at connection, because the majority of connections were from UNIX hosts with large numbers of users, and ident allowed servers as well as channel oporators to differentiate between those users in the case of abuse.

It still functions for that purpose to this day, and is frequently required for hosts that want permission to exceed more than a very small connection limit (usually 2-5 connections). Sometimes, servers will require it even for hosts which aren't shared, because it creates a roadblock for people attempting to IRC from unsecured proxies and from systems where IRC use is prohibited.

Because identd operates on port 113, when using it with a unix-like operating system system such as Linux, you cannot start the service as a normal user - the system administrator will have to install an ident daemon. Most likely, there's one or more available in software repositories for your system. On Windows, no such notion of privileged ports exists, and IRC client software typically provides it's own built-in identd.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing command before joining channel. The command is missing is **USER**. W/out command **USER**. It will wait for  **Ident**. Then, for 5-10 secs then closing link.

In my case:

```
_user = ("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (self.irc_nick, self.irc_host,self.irc_nick))
self.irc_sock.send(bytes(_user, 'UTF-8'))
```

In your case:

```
irc.send('USER %i 8 * :%s\r\n' % (ident, nick))
```

Or even using bytes:

```
irc.send(bytes("USER " + botnick + " " + botnick +" " + botnick + " :python\n", "UTF-8"))
```

Then you send to **NICKSERV IDENTIFY** :

```
irc.send(bytes("NICKSERV IDENTIFY " + botnickpass + " " + botpass + "\n", "UTF-8"))
```